# PDO execute with array returns null

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to use good PDO as always and almost everything works but one query:

```
$primary = 'my_id';
$table = 'my_table';
// This or...
$statement = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT MAX(:id) AS id FROM :table");
        $statement->bindParam(':id', $primary, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(':table', $table, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $statement->execute();

// This one. Both doesn't work.

$statement = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT MAX(:id) AS id FROM :table");
        $statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$arr = array(
            ':id' => 'my_id',
            ':table' => 'my_table',
        );
        $statement->execute($arr);
```

These just return a null array. I feel so confused. So I have tried that:

```
$statement = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT MAX(".$primary.") AS id FROM ".$table);
        $statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $statement->execute();
```

And it works. I feel like I'm missing something but can't figure it out. So clearly there's a problem with binding I tried different variations such as writing one of the variable manually, but no luck so far.

Thanks in advance for any help...

Comment: PLEASE read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-name-as-parameter

Comment: @Fabio I never thought that. That was what I'm missing. Thanks a lot...

Comment: Is there a side effect or how bad would it be if I just check table or columnt name string with regex and use it like "SELECT * FROM $table"?

Answer (score -1):

You can't use parameters as table names in PDO, so you will have to change this to avoid that.  This is not a limitation of PDO, but a limitation of MySQL directly.  The [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/prepare.html) states that

> Parameter markers can be used only where data values should appear,
>   not for SQL keywords, identifiers, and so forth.

Table and column names are identifiers, so using placeholders for them is not supported.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-name-as-parameter) for an alternative method.

Comment: No way for this to be an answer

Comment: @Fabio: Why not? Even the accepted answer in the question you linked to as well says this …

Comment: That's why I posted a comment and you an answer. Comments are not the same as answers. Anyway that answer explains why, you only said: `you can't use, read here`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @RetoKoradi How's that?